# Why is this Scala code to retrieve the current year returning "113"?

Tags: java, scala, date

```
val year=Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getYear().toString
```

I am not getting the correct year. It is giving 113 if the year is 2013, but I want to get 2013.

Comment: I would suggest you use JodaTime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not Scala specific as you noted with your scala tag, you are using the `java.util.Date getYear()` method which is deprecated and

> Returns a value that is the result of subtracting 1900 from the year
>   that contains or begins with the instant in time represented by this
>   Date object, as interpreted in the local time zone

Comment: @frederic you have to know, that scala can use java libraries.

Comment: @Govind sure but the question suggests that the problem comes from Scala or a Scala library

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps this Java code will work better for you:

```
int year=Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

If you have Java 8, you could also try:

```
int year=Year.now().getValue();
```

Comment: Used the Java 8 one directly in the template like `@java.time.Year.now().getValue`